# Why can't I step into a C++ function from C# in mixed-mode debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, mixed-mode

I have a C# application that uses an external C++ DLL, and for some reason, I can't step into its functions anymore in Visual Studio.  I used to be able to, but now, every time I try, I end up in a disassembly inside NTDLL instead of in my C++ function.  If I even put a call to `DebugBreak()` inside the C++ code, I get a bizarre error message like "a breakpoint has been hit that the CLR cannot handle."

I have "*Enable native code debugging*" turned on in the C# application's debug profile, and I've turned off "*Hot Reload*" and "*Edit and Continue*," which sometimes cause trouble for native code debugging, but I still can't step into the C++ code.

Here's my function declaration on the C# side:

```cs
[DllImport("Foo.dll"), SuppressGCTransition]
public static extern unsafe void DoSomething();
```

and here it is on the C++ side:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) void DoSomething()
{
    ...
}
```

Why can't I step into this function?  I'm using Visual Studio 2022, 17.5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason why mixed-mode debugging might not work in this case:  The `[DllImport]` attribute you've applied in C# to the imported C/C++ function declares `SuppressGCTransition`.  That may make the call considerably faster, especially if it's a short call, but it also can really freak out the debugger.  So if you have something like this in C#:

```cs
[DllImport("Foo.dll"), SuppressGCTransition]
public static extern unsafe void DoSomething();
```

You'll need to change it to the form below, or none of the breakpoints inside `DoSomething()` will ever be hit, not even calls to `DebugBreak()`.

```cs
[DllImport("Foo.dll")]
public static extern unsafe void DoSomething();
```

Microsoft states plainly that `SuppressGCTransition` [breaks mixed-mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.suppressgctransitionattribute?view=net-8.0), but it's easy to forget that fact when you're trying to track down why breakpoints aren't working:  There have been enough odd glitches in mixed-mode debugging over the years that it's easy to blame Visual Studio when the fault, is, in fact, your own.

(*I wasted a lot more time today than I ought to have wasted on this exact issue, so hopefully this answer will help someone avoid wasting that time in the future!*)